# Spring boot RabbitMq request/response pattern (reply-to) cannot convert(serialize) received Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using single queue request/response (reply-to) pattern in Spring Boot RabbitMQ. But having exception while sender is recieving Object from Listener.
(It is working if I am sending String instead of Object)

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.example.postgis.rabbit.bitbucket.CarDto]] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.postgis.rabbit.bitbucket.CarDto
```

Config file for server and client

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Obl.png)

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Client {
private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
private final DirectExchange directExchange;

public CarDto send(CarDto carDto) {
    CarDto response = (CarDto) rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(directExchange.getName(), "roytuts", carDto);
            return response ;
}}

@Component
public class Server{
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue.name}")
public CarDto factorial(CarDto carDto) {
    System.out.println("Received request for " + carDto);
    carDto.setName="Nissan";
    return carDto;
}
```

Comment: Do you have `com.example.postgis.rabbit.bitbucket.CarDto` on the server's classpath?

Comment: Your sender is sending `CarDto` as a type, that type isn't available on the receiver. You have to map that type to your own type by configuring the `Jackson2MessageConverter` for Rabbit.

Comment: agulowaty, I have carDto POJO on server's classPath

Comment: M. Deinum, On the listener side I have accepted and send it successfully, but while sender is receiving I have such kind of problem.
-I might be sending it wrongly on server side or on the client side accepting wrong